# Is it good to use CQRS with Mediator pattern in webjobs

Tags: c#, task, cqrs, mediator, webjob

I'm developing a data import application that reads data from multiple CSV files and stores them in a temporary table. And the application process the data from the temp table to multiple tables in the database. Is it good to use the CQRS pattern here? There are some complex logic when processing each CSV file and one CSV file can point to multiple tables in the target database.

I need to know the pros and cons please

Comment: It there's a reason to split the Reads from Writes &/or if there would be convoluted logic referencing all the components from each other then yes. But if its simple then no. Watch the beginning of this video to see what problem CQRS solves and how to weigh it up if its worth using or even needed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yozD5Tnd8nw?t=2m22s For this scenario which could be done with a tool like SSIS or potentially even written as a Serverless Lambda/Function I'd say its overkill. That said I'm using it in all my WebAPI apps.